# C# Problem dll entrypoint inside a class not found

Tags: c#, c++, dll, entry-point

I would like to use a C++ dll of which I don't have an import header.

I am using this software [DLL Export Viewer](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/dll_export_viewer.html) to read the list of functions that the dll contains. all functions are declared as __thiscall, but only one return an object of the main class.

```
public: static class CRfebUsbApp * __cdecl CRfebUsbApp::GetInstance(void)
```

in my ignorance so i tried to create a wrapper in C# to import the exported function

```
[DllImport("lib/CmtRfebUsb.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern IntPtr GetInstance();
```

But when i use this function i am told that no entrypoint was found.

How can i use a function if it is exported inside a class?

Comment: *But when i use this function i am told that no entrypoint was found.* -- What is the *exact* name of the function?  Not the unmangled name, the actual *exact* name, character casing, etc.  One reason for a no entry point found is that you are giving the wrong name, and the way that dynamically loading DLLs work, at least in C++ and using `GetProcAddress` API functions is that it requires the actual name that is exported, odd characters and all.

Comment: BTW, I know what you posted is not the actual name.  Exported DLL's are not beautified like that.  The name is more than likely the name of the function, plus a series of seemingly random `@` signs and other characters (the characters are not really random, they just seem so).

Comment: How can I find the specific name of the function? because CRfebUsbApp :: GetInstance is the name that I find in the dll export viewer.
Can i import the function knowing the address ? .. which in my case is 0x10003000

Comment: When a C++ application is built, the linker that puts together the DLL creates a mangled name.  There is no such function in the DLL that is actually called `CRfebUsbApp::GetInstance(void)` -- that is a beautified, human-readable name for your convenience.   The app you're using is interpreting the mangled name, and outputting back to you the "nice-looking" name.  Use Dependency Walker, or some other utility that gives you the real name of the function.

Comment: thank you very much Dependency, Walker is a very good advice, using the name of the function reported by this software I can create the instantiation of the class !

Comment: Last question ..
if this dll uses a second dll, do I have to manage the dependencies by importing the second dll into my project or does he manage to link the calls if present in the same directory?